# How to change text elements in d3?

Tags: d3.js

Why the d is not an object? and how I can access those text objects? (The following code is wrong)

```
d3.selectAll("svg text").each(function(d, i) {

        d.text("New");
});
```

Comment: I don't think your `selectAll` is formatted properly. What are you trying to grab? All the `text` tags that are inside `svg` tags? Can you provide your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I want to choose all the text tags which start with specific character ('C') , then I want to change them to something else hence I use each function to get them but I can not change the value of them!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside the callback provided to `.each()` the parameter `d` will refer to the data bound to the element. You should use `this` instead which refers to the current element of the iteration. To wrap this into a D3 selection you need to do `d3.select(this)`. This will change your snippet to

```
d3.selectAll("svg text").each(function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).text("New");
});
```

That said, there is an even more concise and elegant way of achieving the same thing where D3 will do the iteration for you without the need to explicitly call `.each()`:

```
d3.selectAll("svg text").text("New");
```

To selectivly edit texts which satisfiy some condition, as mentioned in one of your [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130781/how-to-change-text-elements-in-d3#comment63692890_38130781), you could use [`selection.filter()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections#filter):

```
d3.selectAll("svg text")
  .filter(function() {
    return /^C/.test(d3.select(this).text());  // Check if text begin with a "C"
  })
  .text("New");
```

This will preselect all texts starting with a "C" and change the textual content of these texts only.

Answer (score 3):

It's not changing because you're getting nothing back with your `selectAll`. You need to select your `svg` and then grab all the `text` elements inside of that.

Try this instead:

```
var text = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll('text')
    .each(function(d, i){
        console.log(d)
        d.text("new text")
    })
```

The `console.log(d)`should return back each `text` tag that is inside your `svg`

**EDIT:**

Not the most graceful way to do this, but this should all you to change your text

```
var text = d3.select('svg').selectAll('text')[0]

for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++){
    console.log(text[i].innerHTML = "new")
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bddavidson/mj33c27p/)

Comment: I have this error by your code 'TypeError: d.text is not a function'

Comment: What does `console.log(d)` return back? Also, if you `console.log(text)` after everything, what does that send back as well?

Comment: Bunch of strings (strings inside those text elements)

Comment: this is my reduced svg : <svg><g transform="translate(0,98.57142857142861)" style="opacity: 1;" class="tick"><line y2="0" x2="-6"></line><text class="" y="0" x="-9" style="text-anchor: end;" dy=".32em">C4-h</text></g></svg>

Comment: Hmm. Let me look into it.

Comment: @Iman I've updated my answer. Hopefully that will help you some